# Function is unhookable by Frida

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, frida

I have the following Java code and I'm trying to hook the getTimeZone function:

```java
package com.myapp.models;

public class User {

    private String timeZone;

    public void setTimeZone(String str) {
        this.timeZone = str;
    }

    public String getTimeZone() {
        return this.timeZone;
    }
}
```

This is the frida code I'm trying to use:

```
Java.perform(function () {

    var User = Java.use("com.myapp.models.User");
    User.getTimeZone.implementation = function() {
        console.log("timezone requested")
        return 12;
    };

});
```

However, the hook does not seem to happen since the app crashes on getTimezone not returning a vlue:

```
10-21 12:17:23.013 26553 26553 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myapp.android, PID: 26553
10-21 12:17:23.013 26553 26553 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.myapp.models.User.getTimeZone()' on a null object reference
10-21 12:17:23.013 26553 26553 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.myapp.features.home.logs.updateChart(Presenter.java:370)
10-21 12:17:23.013 26553 26553 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.myapp.features.home.logs.loadGraph(Presenter.java:217)
10-21 12:17:23.013 26553 26553 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.myapp.features.home.logs.onResume(Fragment.java:313)
```

I know that there is no typo in the function and it is identified successfully since I ran in frida:

```
[Redmi Note 7::myapp]-> Java.use("com.myapp.models.User").getTimeZone
function
[Redmi Note 7::myapp]-> Java.use("com.myapp.models.User").getTimeZone.implementation
"0x7e3682a128"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Frida code has one major problem:

The definition of getTimeZone is `String getTimeZone()` hence you have to return a `String`.

But your Frida code return an int value: `return 12;`

Change it to `return "12";` and your Frida code should work.

There may be a second problem in the Android app defining the `User` class (in one of the method `com.myapp.features.home.logs.updateChart` you have not included in your question). Based on the exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.String com.myapp.models.User.getTimeZone()' on a null object reference

the app seems to call `getTimeZone()` without constructing an `User()` instance first. Unless you correct that the Frida hooking code can not work properly.

Comment: Thank you very much but I have not quite understood your second suggestion since I am reversing an existing app and the code which calls this function works.
This is the line of code that calls getTimeZone: Session.getInstance().getUser().getTimeZone(); 
So does the frida code need to be changed besides changing the return value 12 to "12" ? –

Comment: @toothpick You don't have to do more changes on your Frida code. I am not sure if the Exception you got was caused by your wrong return type or if this is a bug of the app you are hooking. My first impression was that `Session.getInstance().getUser()` returns `null` so `getTimeZone()` will always fail (and the Frida code never trigger). Make sure that you are logged on in the app you are hooking.

Comment: getUser was indeed null, the error makes much sense now. thank you very much 